# Create React element from object attribute (with props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In the following code I would like to pass props to the `e.component` element
But i'm getting an error :

**`Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`**

How can i do that ?

> `element={<MainComponent msg={msg} />}` works but it does not meet my needs ❌❌
> The element must be called like this `e.component` ✔️✔️

```
const routes = [
  {
    name: `main`,
    path: `/main`,
    component: <MainComponent />,
  },
]

function MainComponent(props) {
  return <h2>{`Hello ${props.msg}`}</h2>
}

function App() {
  const msg = `world`
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <Routes>
        {routes.map((e, j) => {
          return (
            <Route
              key={`${j}`}
              path={e.path}
              // want to pass "msg" props to e.component ???????
              element={<e.component msg={msg} />}
            />
          )
        })}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what the object `routes` looks like?

Comment: ```routes``` is an array of object (see the post)

Comment: e.component (<MainComponent />) is an component instance. You can not use it like: <c.omponent />. If you want to pass a component prop: pass it like: MainComponent, not <MainComponent  />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to pass additional props ***at runtime*** then you can't pre-specify `MainComponent` as JSX. Instead you could specify `MainComponent` as a reference to the component instead of JSX, and then render it as JSX when mapping. Remember that valid React components are Capitalized or PascalCased.

Example:

```
const routes = [
  {
    name: 'main',
    path: '/main',
    component: MainComponent,
  },
];

function MainComponent(props) {
  return <h2>Hello {props.msg}</h2>;
}

function App() {
  const msg = 'world';
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <Routes>
        {routes.map((e, j) => {
          const Component = e.component;
          return (
            <Route
              key={j}
              path={e.path}
              element={<Component msg={msg} />}
            />
          )
        })}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

````
const routes = [
  {
    name: `main`,
    path: `/main`,
    component: (props) => <MainComponent {...props} />,
  },
]```
````

Answer (score -1):

If you want to render a **component instance**, you have to:

1. pass: component: <MyComponent />
2. use: {component}

If you have to pass a **component**:

1. pass: Component: MyComponent
2. use: <Component />

If you want to pass a **render prop**:

1. pass: component: (params) => <MyComponent {...params} />
2. use: {component()}

Comment: What is that bro!? All i'm asking is a way to pass ```msg``` props to the ```e.component``` element. Your answer is off topic

Comment: What are you talking about. You are passing <MainComponent />, im telling you that it is not correct. You are passing a component instance and expect to use it like component

Comment: You pass component: <MainComponent />, you cant use it again like: <e.component />, you have to pass it like: MainComponent

Comment: This is exactly what i explained, like the accepted answer.